# How to get even array index and change it background color

Tags: javascript, android, arrays, reactjs, react-native

Right now i want to write a function to get the even array index and dynamically change it background color

[image]

Just like the image show above i want select the list item and change it background image.

Comment: please include some relevant codes

Comment: What kind of code you want ?  Code to loop all the list item or ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can achieve this using odd-even index of an array.**

In **JavaScript** you can achieve using below code.

```
$('.js-toprow').each(function(index) {
    if (index % 2 === 0) { // Even
      $(this).css('background', '#ddd');
    } else { // Odd
      $(this).css('background', '#ff0000');
    }        
});
```

In **Android**, you can achieve using below code.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);  
    if (position % 2 == 1) {
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);  
    } else {
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);  
    }
    return view;  
}
```

In **React-Native** you can achieve using below code.

```
renderRow(rowData, sectionID, rowID) {

   let style = [
         styles.row, 
         {'backgroundColor': colors[rowID % colors.length]}
       ];

   return (<View style={style}/>);
 }

 let colors = ['#123456', '#654321', '#fdecba', '#abcdef'];

 let styles = StyleSheet.create({
       row: {
            // .. rows style
       }
 });
```

**OR**

```
(Provided Array).map((array, index) => {
        return (
            <View style={{ backgroundColor: (index % 2 == 0) ? '#ecf0f1' : '#fff' }}>
                <Text>{array.key}</Text>
            </View>
        )
    })
```

Comment: Thanks, how about the method using the map function in react-native ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery,

`$('.items').filter(function(index){
       return index % 2 === 0;
}).css({ 
    background: 'black',
});`